# How do I deal with pseudo forces in a rotating frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Is the centrifugal force the sufficient pseudoforce if my frame of reference is rotating with the same angular velocity as another observed frame which is at a distance $d$ from my frame?

Comment: Is the other frame moving other than rotating

Comment: No. it is totally at rest to me. but has a centripital acceleration with respect to the ground frame.

Comment: If a frame is rotating around a point at a constant angular velocity, and also it has only one radius of rotation (it is thin relative to the radius of rotation, so that parts of it are not a different radii from the center), then we can include only the centripetal pseudo force. But if it does not have a constant angular velocity and is accelerating angularly, then we **must** include that also (which *i think* is usually not possible unless the angular acceleration is varying in a square root fashion)

Answer (score 1):

No, you also need the Coriolis force.

By the way, the motion of any other frame is irrelevant for determining the required inertial forces in your frame.

Comment: thanks! that was really helpful